# Qt - window over modal dialog

Tags: qt, modal-dialog

I have next problem:

I have one modal dialog over main app, but I need to show help dialog of that modal dialog in front of anything (even that modal dialog).
Is there a way to accomplish this without making my modal dialog non-modal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the help dialog would be in front of the modal dialog, how could the user close the modal dialog? The user could not interact with the help dialog in any way. I wouldn't recommend making a user interface that works differently than all other similar interfaces with modal dialogs.

Maybe you could move the help text from the help dialog to the modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Just create another modal style dialog for the help dialog from within the dialog you've already created. You couldn't select select help from anything but that anyway.